# How to index a string array using a variable?

Tags: java, arrays

I mostly familiar with Lua and just getting into Java. Below is the code I am trying to expand upon.

```
s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.programming_languages);
```

What do I do if I want `programming_langugages` to be determined by a variable?

```
testStr = "programming_languages";
```

How can I go about doing something similar to below, where `testStr` is indexed? Below is similar to how I have done it in Lua, so I don't know what else to do, or even search for.

```
testStr = "programming_languages";

s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array[testStr]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java arrays are represented by square brackets:

```java
String [] programmingLanguages = ...
```

You can initialize in-place:

```java
String [] programmingLanguages = {"C", "C++", "Java", "Lua"};
```

Or initialize by index:

```java
String [] programmingLanguages = new String [4];
programmingLanguages[0] = "C";
programmingLanguages[1] = "C++";
programmingLanguages[2] = "Java";
programmingLanguages[3] = "Lua";
```

You can iterate over arrays, access by index and everything:

```java
for(String language : programmingLanguages) {
    System.out.println(language);
}
```

Or:

```java
for(int index=0; index < programmingLanguages.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(programmingLanguages[index]);
}
```

Note that you can't change the size of the array after the memory for it has been allocated, so `programmingLanguage[5]="Pascal"` will throw an exception in runtime.

This might be too restrictive in a real life code challenges, so usually in Java people tend to use `java.util.List` interface and its well-known implementation `java.util.ArrayList`:

```java
List<String> programmingLanguages = new ArrayList<>(); // note, no size specified in advance
programmingLanguages.add("C"); 
programmingLanguages.add("C++");
programmingLanguages.add("Java");
programmingLanguages.add("Lua");
```